# TYPO3 Extbase - Query only records within a certain uid range

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

How can I render only records within a certain uid range? Let's say I want to render only records where it's uid is e.g. higher than 100 and lower than 200

```
/**
 * action list
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction() {

$this->view->assign('records', $this->testRepository->findAll());

}
```

Do I need to use the MathUtility and it's isIntegerInRange ... but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your own function in repository.

Controller

```
/**
 * action list
 *
 * @param integer $minUid
 * @param integer $maxUid
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction() {

    $this->view->assign('records', $this->testRepository->findUidRange($minUid,$maxUid));

}
```

Repository

```
/**
 * Find records filtered by uid from to
 *
 * @param integer $minUid
 * @param integer $maxUid
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface|array The query result
 */
public function findUidRange($minUid = NULL, $maxUid = NULL) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    return $query->matching(
            $query->logicalAnd(
                    $query->greaterThan('uid', $minUid),
                    $query->lessThan('uid', $maxUid),
                    $query->equals('deleted', 0)
            ))->execute();
}
```